# Polynomial property using linear functionals + Vanderomonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following exercise:

> Let $V = \mathbb{R}_{\leq2}[X]$ the vector space of all polynomials of degree 2 or less.
>
> Given three **different** scalars $a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \mathbb{R}$, we define:
>
> $\varphi^1, \varphi^2, \varphi^3:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
>
> $\forall p\in V, \ \ \varphi^i(p) = p(a_i)\ \ 1\leq i\leq 3$
>
> $(\varphi^1, \varphi^2, \varphi^3)$ are a basis for $V^*$, the dual space of $V$
>
> Now, consider the linear functional:
>
> $\varphi:V \to \mathbb{R},\ \ \ $$$\varphi(p) =\int_0^1p(t)dt$$
>
> Prove that there exists $c_1, c_2, c_3 \in \mathbb{R}$, that satisfy:
>
> $\forall p \in V, \ \ $$$\int_0^1p(t)dt = c_1p(a_1) + c_2p(a_2) + c_3p(a_3)$$
>   and write them explicitly.

My attempt:

$\varphi \in V^* \Rightarrow \varphi \in Span(\varphi^1, \varphi^2, \varphi^3)$, and therefore there exists $c_1, c_2, c_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$\varphi = c_1\varphi^1 + c_2\varphi^2 + c_3\varphi^3$

So we say that:

$$\int_0^1p(t)dt =\varphi(p) =  c_1\varphi^1(p) + c_2\varphi^2(p) + c_3\varphi^3(p) = c_1p(a_1) + c_2p(a_2) + c_3p(a_3)$$

proving the first part.

To find $c_1, c_2, c_3$, we use the fact that the above statement is true for all $p\in V$, so we use it on $1, x, x^2$:

$$\varphi(1) = \int_0^1 1\cdot dx = 1 = c_1 + c_2 + c_3$$
$$\varphi(x) = \int_0^1 x\cdot dx = \frac{1}{2} = a_1c_1 + a_2c_2 + a_3c_3$$
$$\varphi(x^2) = \int_0^1 x^2\cdot dx = \frac{1}{3} = a_1^2c_1 + a_2^2c_2 + a_3^2c_3$$

The matrix of the system of equations is:

$\mathbf{A} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
      1 && 1 && 1 \\
      a_1 && a_2 && a_3 \\
      a_1^2 && a_2^2 && a_3^2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
, \ a_1\neq a_2\neq a_3, \mathbf{A}$ is Vandermonde matrix $ \Rightarrow det(\mathbf{A}) \neq 0
$

So, by Cramer's rule:

$$c_1 = \frac{det
\begin{pmatrix}
      1 && 1 && 1 \\
      \frac{1}{2} && a_2 && a_3 \\
      \frac{1}{3} && a_2^2 && a_3^2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
}{det(\mathbf{A})}
$$

$$c_2 = \frac{det
\begin{pmatrix}
      1 && 1 && 1 \\
      a_1 && \frac{1}{2} && a_3 \\
      a_1^2 && \frac{1}{3} && a_3^2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
}{det(\mathbf{A})}
$$

$$c_3 = \frac{det
\begin{pmatrix}
      1 && 1 && 1 \\
      a_1 && a_2 && \frac{1}{2} \\
      a_1^2 && a_2^2 && \frac{1}{3} \\
\end{pmatrix}
}{det(\mathbf{A})}
$$

Is this true?

And, is there a way to, more easily, solve systems which their matrix is Vandermonde? A special way to do Guassian elimination on them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simple way for computing the coefficients $c_i$ is to consider the dual basis $(p_i)$ of the basis $(\varphi^i)$ defined by

$$\varphi^j(p_i)=\delta_{ij}$$
and for example we have

$$p_1=\frac{(x-a_2)(x-a_3)}{(a_1-a_2)(a_1-a_3)}$$